# Bound on integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I need lower and upper bounds (as tight as possible) on the following integral:
$$\int_0^\infty x^n\exp\left(-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}2\right)\, dx$$

$n$ is a real number greater than $0$, and $x_0>0$. I am guessing the bounds will be of the form $B(n)x_0^n+C(n)$, but I don't have a way of showing it (it might not be true either).

EDIT: I guess for the cases $n>1$ and $n<1$, one can use the convexity/concavity of the $x^n$ and make estimates of the form $x_0^n+nxx_0^{n-1}\le(x+x_0)^n\le2^{n-1}(x^n+x_0^n)$.

EDIT: $n$ is not an integer. More importantly, I would like an actual bound on the integral in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: For $x_0=0$ you can find the exact answers from the [moments of a normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments)

Comment: Yes, you get gamma functions.

Comment: @Ivan - what's wrong with gamma functions?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\exp\left(-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2}\right)$$
$$f'(x)=(x_0-x)f(x)$$
$$xf(x)=x_0f(x)-f'(x)$$

Hence

$$I_n(x_0)=\int_0^{\infty}x^nf(x)=x_0I_{n-1}(x_0)-\int_0^{\infty}x^{n-1}f'(x)=
x_0I_{n-1}(x_0)+(n-1)I_{n-2}(x_0)$$

And $I_0(x_0)$ can be computed from the usual error function.
So you get a quick way to compute the results.

Comment: Sorry, I should probably change $n$ to $\alpha$. $n$ is not integer, therefore integration by parts leads nowhere, there is still need to evaluate an integral with $0<n<1$.

Comment: If you're looking for a bound, you can consider that for $n\in(0,1)$, you are between $I_0$ and $I_1$, then you get your polynomial bound by the recursive formula.

Comment: I don't think you are between $I_0$ and $I_1$: $1>x^n>x$ for $x<1$, $1<x^n<x$ for $x>1$.

Comment: For the $n>1$ here is a bound (not very tight). With $n\leq\alpha\leq n+1$,
$$\int_0^1 x^\alpha\exp(-(x-x_0)^2/2)dx\leq \int_0^1 x^n\exp(-(x-x_0)^2/2)dx$$
and
$$\int_1^\infty x^\alpha\exp(-(x-x_0)^2/2)dx\leq \int_1^\infty x^{n+1}\exp(-(x-x_0)^2/2)dx$$
and thus
$$I_\alpha(x_0)\leq I_n(x_0)+I_{n+1}(x_0)$$
and compute $I_n(x_0)$ and $I_{n+1}(x_0)$$ as above.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, for $n>0$, your integral is bounded by:
$$2^{1/2 - n/2} e^{-x_0^2/2} \Gamma(1 + n)$$
This follows by actually calculating the integral which involves hypergeometric functions.